# How to use pandas to resample time series data

Tags: python, pandas

I was trying to resample time series data from 15 minutes to weekly. But it doesn't work out, I read the documentation and many relevant questions but do not understand.

My codes is as follow

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import pandas as pd
import seaborn as sns
%matplotlib inline
Wind = pd.read_csv('C:\WindData.csv')
Wind = Wind.dropna(axis=0, how='any', thresh=None, subset=None, inplace=False) #Drop the nan
Wind.index = pd.to_datetime(Wind['Date'])
Wind_Weekly = Wind['Date'].resample('W').sum()
```

The raw data looks like this

```
Date    Actual   Forecast   Demand
0   01/01/2017 00:00 1049 1011.0 2922 
1   01/01/2017 00:15 961 1029.0 2892 
2   01/01/2017 00:30 924 1048.0 2858 
3   01/01/2017 00:45 852 1066.0 2745
```

After resample, the data become like this

```
Date
2017-01-01    01/01/2017 00:0001/01/2017 00:1501/01/2017 00:...
2017-01-08    01/02/2017 00:0001/02/2017 00:1501/02/2017 00:...
2017-01-15    01/09/2017 00:0001/09/2017 00:1501/09/2017 00:...
2017-01-22    16/01/2017 00:0016/01/2017 00:1516/01/2017 00:...
```

I just want to sum the Actual, Forecast and Demand separately in weekly basis, do you know what I did wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're calling `resample` on a `pd.Series` containing only your `Date` variable as a string, so pandas is summing up the strings by concatenating them together in each row. Change this:

```
Wind_Weekly = Wind['Date'].resample('W').sum()
```

To this:

```
Wind_Weekly = Wind.resample('W').sum()
# Next also works, and removes Date column from the resulting sum
Wind_Weekly = Wind.resample('W')['Actual', 'Forecast', 'Demand'].sum()
```

Calling `Wind['Date']` returns a pd.Series which ONLY contains your dates BEFORE being transformed to `datetime`. So no `Actual`, `Forecast` or `Demand` variables are actually passed to the `resample` call.

You can check that:

```
>>> type(Wind['Date'])
<class 'pandas.core.series.Series'>
```

For testing, I reproduced your problem with the following code:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

rng = pd.date_range('1/1/2012', periods=100, freq='D')
df = pd.DataFrame( # Construct df with a datetime index and some numbers
    {'ones': np.ones(100), 'twos': np.full(100, 2), 'zeros': np.zeros(100)}, 
    index=rng
)
df['Date'] = rng.astype(str) # re-add index as a str
```

In the interpreter:

```
>>> df.resample('W').sum() # works out of the box
            ones  twos  zeros
2012-01-01   1.0     2    0.0
2012-01-08   7.0    14    0.0
2012-01-15   7.0    14    0.0
...

>>> df['Date'].resample('W').sum() # same result as you, only resample 'Date' column
2012-01-01                                           2012-01-01
2012-01-08    2012-01-022012-01-032012-01-042012-01-052012-0...
2012-01-15    2012-01-092012-01-102012-01-112012-01-122012-0...
2012-01-22    2012-01-162012-01-172012-01-182012-01-192012-0...
...
```

Comment: Thanks veryyyy much! Wind_Weekly = Wind.resample('W').sum() does work! But the problem is I found that the weekly sum is not the same with the number I sum by excel. How can I let python knows that my frequency of date is 15 minutes? Then I could get correct number

Comment: @Bi7n You can think of `resample` as `groupby`, but applied on a `datetime` index. The frequency of your original data should not matter: `resample` will just group everything into weeks applying a function to aggregate the results. So whether your data is in minutes, days or hours, if you have n weeks of data, your results should aggregate to those n weeks.

Comment: Thanks for your reply! So, do I need to claim that my frequency is 15 minutes when I set the datetime index? Or do you mean pandas will identify itself and group the data? But I don't know why the result is not the same when I compare the resample data and the sum by excel.

Comment: @Bi7n What I meant is that the frequency of your data shouldn't matter: when resampling, `pandas` groups your data by week and sums, the frequency of your data shouldn't matter in this case. I think the difference might be due to something else.

Comment: To be more specific, after resample the data shows 01/01/2017, 08/01/2017 etc. And sum of 01/01/2017 is the same with my aggregation. But the result of 08/01/2017 is not larger than either 01 to 08, 02 to 08, 08(single day) or 02 to 09, but smaller than 02 to 10.

Comment: The 01/01/2017 label should point to the sum of values from 26/12/2016 to 01/01/2017, while the 08/01/2017 label should point to the sum of values from 02/01/2017 to 08/01/2017 and so on.